# Dynamic SourceData in pivot create

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro of creating a pivot table.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet1!R1C1:R30098C15", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Resultat!R3C1", TableName:="Pivottabell1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Now I want the SourceData to be dynamic with the size of the table.
I have unsuccessfully tried the following

```
' get the rows count and column counts in the R1C1 style
SourceData:="Sheet1!R1C1:R" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row & "C" & Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

' using a "normal" style range with a column far outside the range used
SourceData:="Sheet1!A1:CC" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' using currentregion
SourceData:="Sheet1!" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address

' using currentregion without "$"
SourceData:="Sheet1!" & Replace(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, "$", "")
```

What is wrong with these syntaxes?

Comment: If you actually use a Table, you can simply pass the table name as the source data.

Comment: I don't use a real table. But I could make it a table. It doesn't really matter. Maybe I will switch to a table later if I need it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Without a table, I'd use something like `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Currentregion.Address(referencestyle:=xlr1c1)` to get the address of the range.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to find the error on one of the syntaxes.

The code adds a new sheet to add the pivot table on, and since I forgot to add sheets() on columns part it didn't work.

This is a working syntax.

```
SourceData:="Sheet1!R1C1:R" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row & "C" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
                                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```